# Radio button styled with -webkit-appearance: checkbox: indeterminate state in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

We have a multiple choice quiz on our site, and Django spits the form out as radio buttons. The people who make such decisions want the radio buttons to be checkboxes, so we've styled them with `webkit-appearance: checkbox;`. This looks OK in all browsers except Chrome. Chrome renders the checkboxes in the indeterminate state (with a line through the middle).

Is there a way to tell Chrome to render them as unchecked?

If it comes down to it, I will customize the form widget in Django, but for now I'd like to do it in CSS or JS.

Note: you can see this behavior yourself here:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    -moz-appearance: checkbox;
    -ms-appearance: checkbox;     /* not currently supported */
    -o-appearance: checkbox;      /* not currently supported */
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 2</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but you could add a hidden radio button, which is checked.  This will clear the indeterminate state of the other radio buttons:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;
  -ms-appearance: checkbox;     /* not currently supported */
  -o-appearance: checkbox;      /* not currently supported */
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio"> Checkbox 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio" class="hidden" checked>
```